# Is there a way to get the Absolute Path for links with a WebPack?

Tags: webpack, path, absolute-path

I have such a WebPack configuration.

I have established a publicPath: ' / '  - but it looks like it does not work.

I have used "webpack": "^3.12.0" and "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2" if this is important

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.js", "./src/styles/main.scss"],
  output: {
     filename: "bundle.js",
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/dist"),
     publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
     rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(["css-loader", "sass-loader"])
        },

        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"],
            plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
          }
        }
     ]
  },
  devServer: {
     contentBase: "./public/",
     watchContentBase: true,
     port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [
     new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css"),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
     }),
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

But my link in the tag a :

```
<a href="/">Text</a>
```

still leads to localhost:3000

Is there a way to get the absolute path for links ?

Comment: <a> tag href attribute has nothing to do with webpack. Whenever we give `/` in the href, it will always direct to the base url which is `localhost:3000/` in local, and it will be the server url (say, `mydomain.com/`) if it is deployed somewhere. What are we expecting to happen here?

Comment: Yes, you probably are right - WebPack has nothing to do with it.
I was looking for a problem in the wrong place.